# Azure Data Factory V2 how to process azure analysis service cube

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-analysis-services, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory V2, how to process azure analysis service cube?

I am able to use Azure Automation Account to run runbook powershell script to process cube automatically. However, I want to add cube processing into my ETL process developed on ADF V2.

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set-up a Webhook from the Azure Automation runbook and call that URL endpoint from an ADF pipeline Web Activity using POST method.

Or, here is an example of processing AAS cubes using Web Activity, but calling a Logic Apps endpoint instead of an Automation Webhook (Thanks to Jorg Klein for this tip):

https://jorgklein.com/2018/01/30/process-azure-analysis-services-objects-from-azure-data-factory-v2-using-a-logic-app/

Comment: Just keep in mind you need to enable the incoming firewall from the automation account into the SSAS cube, and the automation account could be on any number if different IP's

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach for processing Azure Analysis Services from ADFv2 is to use built-in Web Activities along with the built-in MSI authentication. A sample can be found [here](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/README.md#processazureas).